# PhanthomJS - How do you capture continuous requests?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

If you go to CNBC.COM and open your debugging tools in "Chrome" or whichever browser you prefer, you can see the network trace. Once the page loads, the quote data for the stocks continuously update.

You'll see something similar like this repeating every few seconds.

```
http://quote.cnbc.com/quote-html-webservice/quote.htm?partnerId=2&requestMethod=quick&exthrs=1&noform=1&fund=1&output=jsonp&symbols=.SPX|.IXIC|.RUT|.VIX|.GDAXI|.FTSE|.FCHI|.FTMIB|.STOXX|.N225|.SSEC|.HSI|.AXJO|.KS11|%40CL.1|%40LCO.1|%40NG.1|%40RB.1|%40HO.1|%40SI.1|%40GC.1|%40HG.1|%40PL.1|%40PA.1|US10Y|DE10Y-DE|JP10Y-JP|UK10Y-GB|FR10Y-FR|EUR%3D&callback=quoteHandler1
```

When I use the following code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
page.open(url)
```

I see all the initial requested resources for the page. But, not the continuous quote data. I tried setting timeouts `setTimeout()` for like 20 seconds, to give it additional time to capture the additional requests, but it doesn't.

I just need like 20 seconds worth of additional capture of all the requests to get a few additional qoute.cnbc.com in the trace.

I just started using PhantomJS and I tried just about everything I seen on the web and stackoverflow and nothing helped.

Comment: Interesting task. Unfortunately, quotes are requested with the help of JSONP and it seems the result cannot be intercepted. Theoretically you could hijack `CNBC_Quotes.QuoteRetriever.prototype.getData` and replace its callback with your function, but you would have to reverse-engineer module loading on the site. I think it's simpler to just periodically scrape tickers where quotes are displayed.